# User Context on Post to Chatter

Tags: chatter, visual-flows

I have a client that is the only user on her org. Her profile is System Admin.

I need to create a Flow that posts to Chatter. The problem is that her user profile will be the one to run the Flow, so she will be the user context, and Chatter won't let you post to yourself -- so the notification never comes. In other orgs, I've simply logged in as a different admin to activate the flow, but there's not another user I can log in as.

I tried posting to a Chatter Group that she follows, and while it shows up in the Chatter Group feed, it doesn't create a system notification badge at the top, which is the indicator I really need to accomplish.

Any ideas on a workaround?

Comment: The user can create a Chatter Stream that includes the relevant record or records. A Chatter post to any such record will create a notification. I believe that's the only way to force Chatter to notify other than directly tagging a user.

Comment: Thx @DavidReed, I'll pursue that direction.